# Excel sheet is not working from server in c#

Tags: c#

Hi i am downloding excel report, it is not working when download from server but it is working on local machine

Error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). at CompanyStatics.btnexport_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\TestAdmin\CompanyStatics.aspx.cs:line 959

Code:

```
using ExcelAutoFormat = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

 c# Code on button click
  protected void btnexport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int companyId = Convert.ToInt32((ddlCompanyName.SelectedValue));

        try
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("exportedfiles\\");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            File.Delete(path + "Company&VesselDetails.xlsx");


            var xlAppToExport = new Excel.Application();
            xlAppToExport.Workbooks.Add("");
            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheetToExport = default(Excel.Worksheet);
            xlWorkSheetToExport = (Excel.Worksheet)xlAppToExport.Sheets["Sheet1"];

            int iRowCnt = 2;
            int iRowCnt1 = 5;

            // Add company Name
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[1, 1] = "Company Name";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range rangeComp = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[1, 1] as Excel.Range;
            rangeComp.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            rangeComp.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            rangeComp.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            rangeComp.ColumnWidth = 40.0;
            //rangeComp.HorizontalAlignment =ri;;
            //end company Name
            // Add Token Name
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[1, 2] = "Total Tokens";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range rangeTokens = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[1, 2] as Excel.Range;
            rangeTokens.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            rangeTokens.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            rangeTokens.EntireRow.RowHeight = 30.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            rangeTokens.ColumnWidth = 40.0;
            //end Token Name
            // Add Approve Token
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[1, 3] = "Approve Tokens";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range ApproveToken = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[1, 3] as Excel.Range;
            ApproveToken.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            ApproveToken.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            ApproveToken.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            ApproveToken.ColumnWidth = 25.0;
            //end Approve Token
            // Add Remaining Tokens
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[1, 4] = "Remaining Tokens";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range RemainingTokens = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[1, 4] as Excel.Range;
            RemainingTokens.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            RemainingTokens.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            RemainingTokens.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            RemainingTokens.ColumnWidth = 25.0;
            //end Remaining Tokens
            // Add Remaining Tokens
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[4, 1] = "Vessel Name";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range VesselName = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[4, 1] as Excel.Range;
            VesselName.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            VesselName.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            VesselName.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            VesselName.ColumnWidth = 40.0;
            // Add Remaining Tokens
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[4, 2] = " Ship Email ID";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range ShipEmailID = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[4, 2] as Excel.Range;
            ShipEmailID.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            ShipEmailID.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            ShipEmailID.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            ShipEmailID.ColumnWidth = 40.0;
            // Add Remaining Tokens
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[4, 3] = "Total Tokens (300)";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range TotalTokens = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[4, 3] as Excel.Range;
            TotalTokens.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            TotalTokens.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            TotalTokens.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            TotalTokens.ColumnWidth = 25.0;
            //end Remaining Tokens
            // Add Remaining Tokens
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[4, 4] = "Assigned Tokens (99)";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range AssignedTokens = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[4, 4] as Excel.Range;
            AssignedTokens.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            AssignedTokens.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            AssignedTokens.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            AssignedTokens.ColumnWidth = 25.0;
            //end Remaining Tokens
            // Add Remaining Tokens
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[4, 5] = "Remaining Tokens (201)";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range Remaining = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[4, 5] as Excel.Range;
            Remaining.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            Remaining.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            Remaining.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            Remaining.ColumnWidth = 25.0;
            //end Remaining Tokens
            // Add Package Start
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[4, 6] = "Start Date";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range pkgstart = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[4, 6] as Excel.Range;
            pkgstart.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            pkgstart = (Excel.Range)xlAppToExport.Cells[4, 6];
            pkgstart.EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy";

            pkgstart = (Excel.Range)xlAppToExport.Cells[4, 6];
            pkgstart.HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
            pkgstart.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);

            pkgstart.get_Range("F1", "G1").Cells.HorizontalAlignment =
                 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
            //string startRange = "A1";
            //string endRange = "A1";

            //Excel.Range currentRange = (Excel.Range)xlAppToExport.get_Range(startRange, endRange);
            //currentRange.Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;

            //pkgstart.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignLeft;
            // Set Row Height.
            pkgstart.EntireRow.RowHeight = 50.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            pkgstart.ColumnWidth = 10.0;
            //end Package Start
            // Add Last Update 
            xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[4, 7] = "Last Update Date";
            // Get the range from excel.
            Excel.Range lastupdate = xlAppToExport.ActiveCell.Worksheet.Cells[4, 7] as Excel.Range;
            lastupdate.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.SteelBlue);
            // Set font color.
            lastupdate.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.White);
            // Set Row Height.
            lastupdate.EntireRow.RowHeight = 25.0;
            // Set Column Width.
            lastupdate.ColumnWidth = 25.0;
            //end Last Update Date            
            for (int i = 0; i < gvCompany.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                string sid = gvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text;
                string cmpl = gvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[4].Text;
                string kpit = gvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text;
                string tcs = gvCompany.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text;

                xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 1] = sid;
                xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 2] = cmpl;
                xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 3] = kpit;
                xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt, 4] = tcs;
                iRowCnt = iRowCnt + 1;

                string query = string.Empty;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                query = "select vesselID, vesselName,ShipEmailID, CompanyMasterId , ISNULL(AllowToken, 0 ) as 'AllowToken', ISNULL(AssignTokenToEmp, 0 ) as 'Total Assign Token',( ISNULL(AllowToken, 0 ) - ISNULL(AssignTokenToEmp, 0 )) as 'RemainingToken' from Vessel where CompanyMasterID =" + companyId;

                dt = SqlHelper.ReturnDataTable(query);
                divcrew.Visible = true;
                gvvessel.AllowPaging = false;
                gvvessel.DataSource = dt;
                gvvessel.DataBind();

                for (int j = 0; j < gvvessel.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    // gvvessel.AllowPaging = false;

                    Label lblvess = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblvesselName");
                    string myVal = lblvess.Text;
                    Label lblShipEmail = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblShipEmailID");
                    string mylblShipEmail = lblShipEmail.Text;
                    Label lblAllowTo = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblAllowToken");
                    string mylblAllowTo = lblAllowTo.Text;
                    Label lblAssignToken = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblAssignToken");
                    string mylAssignToken = lblAssignToken.Text;
                    Label lblRemainingT = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblRemainingToken");
                    string mylRemainingT = lblRemainingT.Text;
                    Label lblpkg = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lblpackagedate");
                    string myVal1 = lblpkg.Text;
                    Label lbllastupd = (Label)gvvessel.Rows[j].FindControl("lbllastupdate");
                    string myVal2 = lbllastupd.Text;
                    //gvvessel.SetPageIndex(j);

                    xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt1, 1] = myVal;
                    xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt1, 2] = mylblShipEmail;
                    xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt1, 3] = mylblAllowTo;
                    xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt1, 4] = mylAssignToken;
                    xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt1, 5] = mylRemainingT;

                    // string date = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myVal1) && myVal1!="----")
                    //{
                    //    date = DateTime.ParseExact(myVal1,"dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    //}

                    //else if (myVal1 =="----")
                    //{
                    //    lblpkg.Text = "--------";
                    //}

                    xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt1, 6] = myVal1;
                    xlWorkSheetToExport.Cells[iRowCnt1, 7] = myVal2;
                    iRowCnt1 = iRowCnt1 + 1;
                }
                // SAVE THE FILE IN A FOLDER.
                xlWorkSheetToExport.SaveAs(path + "Company&VesselDetails.xlsx");
                // CLEAR.
                xlAppToExport.Workbooks.Close();
                xlAppToExport.Quit();
                xlAppToExport = null;
                xlWorkSheetToExport = null;
                //string path = Server.MapPath("exportedfiles\\");

                // CHECK IF THE FOLDER EXISTS.
                if (Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    // CHECK IF THE FILE EXISTS.
                    if (File.Exists(path + "Company&VesselDetails.xlsx"))
                    {
                        string sPath = Server.MapPath("exportedfiles\\");

                        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Company&VesselDetails.xlsx");
                        Response.TransmitFile(sPath + "Company&VesselDetails.xlsx");
                        Response.End();

                    }
                }
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblshowexcelerror.Text = ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {


        }
```

Comment: Is Excel installed on the server?

Comment: No excel is not install on server

Comment: This code is trying to automate Excel, and as far as I can understand, is running on the server. The server must have Excel installed in order for this to work.

Comment: Any other solution if excel is not install on server

Comment: hi sir kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use COM objects you should have MS Excel installed on server machine. Otherwise you are going to need third-party libraries to manually work with .xls and .xlsx files.

One such library is [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) which works with new .xlsx files. It have worked for me and I know many others exist.